# Error when making CommandBinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make some shortcuts for my `Menu` in WPF. I made a static class with `RoutedCommands` but I can't get it  to work. It says that my markup is invalid, but I wrote everything fine. The error I get is: 'None+D6' key and modifier combination is not supported for KeyGesture. I haven't used D6 anywhere in my `RoutedCommands`.

Relevant XAML

```
Window x:Class="WorldResources.GlowingEarth"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:WorldResources.View"/>
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="cmd:RoutedCommands.NewMap" Executed="NewFile_Click" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></DockPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New">
                <MenuItem Header="_Map" Command="cmd:RoutedCommands.NewMap" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

And here is my `RoutedCommands` class

```
static class RoutedCommands
{
    public static RoutedUICommand NewMap = new RoutedUICommand(
        "New Map",
        "NewMap",
        typeof(RoutedCommands),
        new InputGestureCollection()
        {
            new KeyGesture(Key.M & Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control & ModifierKeys.Shift)
        }
        );
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Key.M & Key.A evaluates to a new key value

Comment: Are you trying to create a gesture invoked by pressing the <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> keys simultaneously, plus the two modifieers? Or what VS irritatingly calls a "chord", like <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> *followed by* <kbd>Shift+M</kbd>? If it's the former, that's not supported out of the box, but [according to an answer here it's doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181991/multi-key-gesture-in-wpf). The latter seems like it might involve roping all your key bindings into a bizarro state machine. I bet it'd be fun to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `KeyGesture` is invalid. Try this if you want to handle CTRL+Shift + M and CTRL+Shift + A:

```
static class RoutedCommands
{
    public static RoutedUICommand NewMap = new RoutedUICommand(
        "New Map",
        "NewMap",
        typeof(RoutedCommands),
        new InputGestureCollection()
        {
            new KeyGesture(Key.M, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift),
            new KeyGesture(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift)
        }
        );
}
```